# How to declare type according to the enum using Javascript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum and I want to declare the type according to that enum.
For example,

```
enum Animals {
  CAT = 'cat',
  DOG = 'dog',
}
```

And from that `Animal` I want to declare type like this

```
type MyType = {
  cat_price: string,
  cat_from: string,
  cat_color: string,
  dog_price: string,
  dog_from: string,
  dog_color: string,
}
```

So if I modify the `Animal` enum, the `MyType` will be modified automatically.
How can I do this?
Any comment will be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered `type MyType = Record<Animals, AnimalData>` instead? It's cleaner design and easier to get the types right. (Disregard this advice if you need this to work with an API you have no control over.)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, can you explain in better words?

Comment: @Thomas, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: A value would look like `{'cat': {'price': '€ 42.00', 'from': 'Amsterdam', 'color': '#deadbeef'}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, this is actually possible in TypeScript thanks to [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
enum Animals {
  CAT = 'cat',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

type AnimalData = {
  price: number,
  from: string,
  color: string,
}

type MyType = {
  [Key in keyof AnimalData as `${Animals}_${Key}`]: AnimalData[Key]
}

const foo: MyType = {
  cat_price: 42,
  cat_from: 'Africa',
  cat_color: 'teal',
  dog_price: '37',  // Error! Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  dog_from: 'Mexico',
  dog_colr: 'blue', // Error! Object literal may only specify known
                    // properties, but 'dog_colr' does not exist in type
                    // 'MyType'. Did you mean to write 'dog_color'?
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbAzlA3gKClAwjACpQC8UA5AMZIAuFANLlACIDyA4mZQCYD2Ac0bYAvtmy0AngAdgsBMhQs6SbjjzSATvCrAAXFHAQARsE1M8AM018IBtLW0gBFqFT4o+m+4-jOmYhIycgCykkTBaswA2gDSwJJQflAA1gl8lvKIqMq0qkgYAAYAJJhw2egiAPql8ZIihQC6BuWKuUhxCY2i4u4gDlCWfHwGYRGyUXg0tFVaOvpQACwATK7TVda2BhQw1jpIwlN0Ve6e3pS0wKiHUPwCs9q62wDMAOw3dxs2dpQhwAAeOj4H0EJw85woxhQYGAwhEQA)

Comment: Wow, thanks @Thomas. It works very well. But how can I declare the optional type?
For example, I would like to make `cat_price` and `dog_price` optional.

Comment: @BikasLin Edited to make it more flexible, allowing a different type for each key.